# Visual Studio optimizes to different behavior in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, release-mode

I have a C++ application developed with Visual Studio 2010. I have a static method, which is called to decode messages received via serial hardware.

When I use the "Release" configuration, the compiler somehow optimizes the method in a strange way and the method doesn't work as expected. When I use the "Debug" configuration, everything is fine.

Here's the method:

```
std::vector<BYTE> CMsg::DecodeMsg(std::vector<BYTE> & msg)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> asciiDecoded;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < msg.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        auto val2 = BaseUtils::hex2Ascii(msg.at(i++), msg.at(i));
        asciiDecoded.push_back(val2);
    }

    return asciiDecoded;
}
```

I think there is something messed up with the i-variable caused by some optimizations (I use /O2) in Release configuration.

Comment: I believe `msg.at(i++), msg.at(i)` is UB.

Comment: The additional increment of the variable inside the for loop in general or just the msg.at(i++) is undefined behavior?

Comment: No, it's about [using both `i` and `i++` in the same parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7568163/11683).

Comment: You're right. Using BaseUtils::hex2Ascii(msg.at(i), msg.at(i + 1)); and afterwards just a i++; solved the issue. Thanks! Thanks also for the link

Comment: Comment of GSerg solved the issue.

Comment: @Simon: you should also fix the function to properly handle an empty `msg` argument.

Comment: You are right, but this is already checked, before this method can be called